# How to ensure stream reading fails if length exceeds a limit

Tags: .net, file-upload, stream

I am creating an API endpoint for uploading large files. These should not be buffered in memory (at least not in their entirety), and will be streamed directly to the DB or to disk.

There are [official Microsoft docs on streaming uploads to DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#upload-large-files-with-streaming), but it does not show how to ensure in an unbuffered way that you don't read files larger than the limit. (The code in the sample repo has [a helper that checks this by reading the entire file into memory](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/770ad0b382d5074d3b601b805b94eee78fe39036/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp/Utilities/FileHelpers.cs#L149-L193), which defeats the purpose of streaming in the first place.)

Is there a (preferably simple) way to make the streaming fail when it reads more bytes than some specified limit? Are there perhaps other ways to ensure that users can't upload too large files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/267#issue-248095111) explains how to set size limits globally and per request when using Kestrel.

Per request using attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequestSizeLimit(100_000_000)]
public IActionResult MyAction([FromBody] MyViewModel data)
{
```

Per request using `IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature`:

```
app.Run(async context =>
{
    context.Features.Get<IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature>().MaxRequestBodySize = 100_000_000;
```

Global default:

```
.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
```